# Making responsive table out of normal HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table, html4

So,

I've made an email, with HTML4.01
Strickly using nested tables.

```
<body bgcolor="#666666">
    <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#666666">
        <tr>
            <td width="600" height="60">
                <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="600" height="60" align="center"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#FFFFFF"><br>
                        Etkö näe tätä viestiä?  <a href="#" style="color: #ffffff;">Siirry HTML-versioon</a>
              </span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Like this, for example. There is over 800 lines of code in this one document.
Now i've been asked to make a resposive single page site out of the same content.

My question is, is there a easy or semi-easy way to make responsive page out of HTML tables ?

As you can see, there is lots of hard-coded widths and heights

I would love to skip some of the work with some crazy css trick.
I did a google search and found this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp but it didnt do anything, atleast for now.

Comment: If you want it easy, you can add something like `@media (max-width: 800px) {
  table, tbody, tr {display:block}
  td, th {display:inline-block}
}` to the css...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just noticed the `width="600"` in your source. Remove all those. Fixed width is counterproductive for responsiveness. Also, is your table only one td wide? What purpose does that have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style 1#

I removed all the pixel and point fixed sizes inside every td and tr.
It was painful and slow and i much rather use #2 now...

Style #2

I just redid everything with **bootstrap grids**,
once you understand bootstrap grid, its way faster than looking for fixed sizes in tables. It will also be much easier to make changes once you have your template.